# Edge intersections of paths

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to read up on the nonrepetitive graph coloring problem. That's for context, my question can be answered without referring to the problem.

I have a graph G, and I am interested in looking at paths of even lengths. A paper I am referring to claims that a path of length $2i$ can at most intersect with $4ij\Delta^{2j}$ paths of length $2j$.

Edge intersections are implied here. $\Delta$ represents the maximum degree in the graph.

I am not sure how the quantity $4ij\Delta^{2j}$ is achieved. I have tried to think about it in a few ways, but no luck.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

Say we're given a path of length $2i$, and we want to find a path of length $2j$ that intersects the first path.

We have $2i$ choices for which vertex on the first path the paths intersect at. Call this vertex $v$.

We have $2j$ choices for "how far along" the second path $v$ is. That is, pick $0 \leq k \leq 2j - 1$ and say there are $k$ vertices of the second path on one side of $v$ and $2j - 1 - k$ on the other side.

Then we need to pick $2j-1$ vertices to form that path. For each of these, there are potentially $\Delta$ choices, giving $\Delta^{2j-1}$ choices in total.

Combining all of these gives $4ij\Delta^{2j-1} \leq 4ij\Delta^{2j}$ choices for the path of length $2j$.

This is clearly an overestimate, but that's fine, we just wanted an upper bound.